# Criar restrição unique com dois campos no request do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request, laravel-5.3

Tenho na migration de criação da minha tabela o seguinte:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('database2')->create('empresa_funcoes', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('empresa_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('funcao_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            //Create a Unique Constraint
            $table->unique(['empresa_id', 'funcao_id'], 'empresa_funcao');

            //Create Foreign Keys
            $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('funcao_id')->references('id')->on('funcoes')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

No meu request preciso criar uma restrição para que não consiga cadastrar uma função 2x para uma mesma empresa.

Tenho isso até o momento no meu EmpresaFuncaoRequest, mas não posso simplesmente colocar um `unique` ali porque ele não vai deixar eu cadastrar essa função para outra empresa.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'funcao_id' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

O que posso fazer?

> Não estou pedindo pra validar o empresa_id porque está indo em um
>   hidden, não sei se influencia.

Comment: você ta querendo bloquear `empresa_id` e `funcao_id` se forem iguais correto?

Comment: Isso, pra não deixar enviar a função X pra empresa Y caso já tenha essa função nesta emrpesa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie uma [regra de validação customizada](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules), porque, o seu caso é particular, eu dei uma olhada nas regras atuais, acho que nenhuma consiga fazer o que você precisa, talvez em partes, então faça a sua regra própria criando primeiramente um [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers):

> `php artisan make:provider UniqueKeyDupleServiceProvider`

Na pasta `app/Providers` edite o arquivo criado: `UniqueKeyDupleServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\EmpresaFuncao;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


class UniqueKeyDupleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{


    public function boot()
    {
        \Validator::extend('uniquekeyduple', 
                    function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
        {
            $value1 = (int)request()->get($parameters[0]);
            if (is_numeric($value) && is_numeric($value1))
            {
                return (!(EmpresaFuncao::where($attribute, $value)
                    ->where($parameters[0], $value1)
                    ->count() > 0));
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

dentro desse [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) foi feito uma adição da [validação customizada](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) e dentro tem o `model` `EmpresaFuncao` que faz a pesquisa para averiguar se existem registro para uma determinada **empresa** se a **função** ***já foi cadastrada***. Se já existe ele não deixa prosseguir e não realiza o método que está utilizado essa regra.

Após a criação [registre o seu providers da seguinte maneira](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#registering-providers): no arquivo `config/app.php` vai até o `array` de `providers` e adicione esse novo `provider` da seguinte forma:

```
'providers' => [
    // Other Service Providers

    App\Providers\UniqueKeyDupleServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Na função de [request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) (`EmpresaFuncaoRequest`) adicione a regra criada com o nome de `uniquekeyduple` tendo como parâmetro o campo `funcao_id`, sendo enfim: `uniquekeyduple:funcao_id`, segue código exemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;    
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EmpresaFuncaoRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'empresa_id' => 'required|uniquekeyduple:funcao_id'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'empresa_id.uniquekeyduple' => 'Função existente!'
        ];
    }
}
```

Finalizando no `Controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\EmpresaFuncaoRequest;
use App\Http\Requests;

class EmpresaFuncaoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('empresafuncao');
    }

    public function store(EmpresaFuncaoRequest $request)
    {
        //faça as operações que assim desejar
        return $request->all();
    }
}
```

<sub>**Isso é um exemplo funcional, pode ser melhorado ainda mais, mas, feito para o seu caso em especifico.**</sub>

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers)
- [Registering Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#registering-providers)
- [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Boa tarde, e na atualização como posso para ele ignorar ele mesmo, porque eu tenho um campo de arquivo que faço upload, e agora não deixa eu atualizar?

Comment: @UlissesGimenes abra um novo quetionamento e explica o que precisa. Ok?

Comment: Consegui fazer, mas as vezes fiz coisas de mais no provider mas funcionou!!

Comment: No meu caso estava a ter o erro `Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateRequired|uniquekeyduple does not exist.`. Então, no Request simplesmente alterei a rule() para `'required','uniquekeyduple:funcao_id'`. (+1, excelente resposta)