# Fazer uma validação personalizada no laravel 5

Tags: laravel, validação, request

Tenho um sistema em laravel 5.
Tenho um Form Request validando os campos de um form com algumas regras.

E precisava fazer o seguinte:
Tenho uma aba no formulário que cadastra os sócios de uma empresa.
O usuário tem a opção de cadastrar ou não os sócios. Tenho um checkbox que controla isso, ele vem "false" por padrão...Aí se o usuário quiser cadastrar o sócio, ele "checa" o checkbox para preencher os dados dos sócios.

Gostaria de fazer uma função que se o checkbox do socio estiver marcado, ele faz a validation nos campos: - nome, - participação.
Senão, ele não faz a validation nesses campos.

Vi uma maneira de criar um ServiceProvider pra isso, mas como vou pegar o campo "cadsocios"(checkbox) e verificar se ele tem valor dentro de uma Request no laravel?

Comment: qual é a versão do seu Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um campo que pode ou não ser obrigatório que depende de outro campo (*no seu caso é um* `checkbox`), deve-se usar o [`required_if`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#available-validation-rules) que a segue a nomenclatura:

> `required_if`**:**`anotherfield,value`

**Exemplo:**

Nos campos abaixo tem um `input` do tipo `checkbox` com o valor `true`, que se estiver checado o `input` do tipo `text` com o nome de `nome` tem que ter no minimo **1** letra digitada:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="liberar">
    <input type="text" value="" name="nome">
</p>
```

no seu [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation):

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         'nome' => 'required_if:liberar,true'
    ];
}
```

---

***No seu código ficaria algo assim:***

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="socio">
    <input type="text" value="" name="nome">
    <input type="text" value="" name="participacao">
</p>
```

---

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
         'nome' => 'required_if:liberar,true',
         'participacao' => 'required_if:liberar,true'
    ];
}
```

---

Não vejo motivos para montar um validação customizada, mas, [tem um link com o passo a passo, se assim preferir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157107/54880).

Comment: Ficou show de bola... mas, surgiu um imprevisto em outro campo...

Comment: no campo nome, é um input text podendo ter varios campos nomes = nome[] (array), aí ele não aceita na validação, já que mesmo estando vazio, ele considera existente...existe uma forma pra isso?

Comment: Se pode abrir outro pergunta foi resolvido esse problema agora é outro. Entendeu

Comment: Tem sim como validar array

Comment: No link da pergunta tem as validaçoes array e in_array no site do laravel ou então abra outra pergunta, tudo bem?

Comment: abri outra pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158381/valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-no-laravel-5

Answer (score 1):

No Service Provider que faz a validação pode usar o `$this`, porquê ele referencia do Request do Controller.

```
public function rules()
{
    if($this->nome_do_campo){

    }
    else{

    }
}
```