# Validação no Laravel 5 em campos do tipo array?

Tags: laravel, validação, request

Através de colaboradores do site consegui tirar uma dúvida na pergunta [*Fazer uma validação personalizada no laravel 5*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157823/54880) sobre validação no **Laravel**, onde foi possível, validar um campo `input` `text` ***somente*** se um ***ComboBox*** for checado.

**Exemplo:**

> `required_if`:`anotherfield`,`value`

E agora surgiu outra dúvida, tenho vários campos **nome**, que é um `input` `text`  `nomes = nome[] (array)`, aí no caso acima ele não aceita na validação, já que mesmo estando vazio, ele considera ***existente*** devido a existência do array

Existe uma forma pra isso?

Comment: coloque um exemplo de `input` seria `<input type="text" name="nome[]"/>`??? e todas as informações possiveis da dúvida. Veja que minha edição fez referencia até a sua primeira dúvida, que foi tirada, e com menção de uma nova duvida!

Comment: É o seguinte: tenho varios inputs para se cadastrar vários sócios da empresa, todos os campos tem o name = nome[], ou seja, quando faço um get no campo nome, ele vem como um array de nomes, de acordo com a quantidade de campos nome[] preenchidas... Mas quando Faço a validaçao pelo : >required_if: ... Ele não funciona, e mesmo não tendo sido preenchido nenhum nome, ele passa direto e nao acusa na validação ... Imagino q aconteça isso, pois quando o array de nomes é passado para a validação, o Request acusa que está ok pois existe valor(que é o array), mas ele nao verifica se o array tem valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) precisa saber que o campo nome é um [`array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) e o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) já tem um forma de ***validar*** o campo só precisa ter a seguinte nomenclatura:

> `nome_do_campo` + `.*`

Como os seus campos são relacionados os dois precisa seguir a nomenclatura `nome.*` **e** `liberar.*` na parte da validação, já na parte do formulário (`<form>`) segue exemplo abaixo:

```
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="liberar[]">
    <input type="text" value="" name="nome[]">
</p>
<p>
    <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="liberar[]">
    <input type="text" value="" name="nome[]">
</p>
```

Também segue um exemplo de [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation):

```
class ExemploRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nome.*' => 'required_if:liberar.*,true'
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [                
            'nome.required_if' => 'nome é para ser digitado'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Recomendação:** *você deve controlar também a validação com `Javascript` para enviar os dados praticamente correto, e esses campos são sequencias tome bastante cuidado com isso.*

- [`Validating Arrays`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#validating-arrays)

Comment: Show de bola, era exatamente isso. valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um asterisco para simbolizar qualquer campo do array (nome.*), eu não entendi exatamente o que você quer, então eu aconselho a dar uma olhada na documentação do Laravel na parte de validação de array, deve te ajudar:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#validating-arrays