# ERRO ao criar restrição unique com dois campos no request do Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validação, http-request

Tentei implementar [um exemplo que encontrei aqui no StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157107/54880) porem sem sucesso.

***REGRA:***

- *Unique dupla (user_created - descrição) / Código Usuario que criou e Descrição*
- *Outro usuário poderia criar a mesma informação porem que seja uma única vez.*

**CORRETO:**

```
|ID|USER_CREATED|DESCRICAO|

|1|1|DESCARGA|

|2|2|DESCARGA|
```

***INCORRETO:***

```
|ID|USER_CREATED|DESCRICAO|

|1|1|DESCARGA|

|2|1|DESCARGA|
```

---

Criei o `Provider` e alterei o método `boot`:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Validator::extend('uniquekeyduple',
        function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
        {
            $value1 = (int)request()->get($parameters[0]);
            if (is_numeric($value) && is_numeric($value1))
            {
                return (!(InfoAdd::where($attribute, $value)
                        ->where($parameters[0], $value1)
                        ->count() > 0));
            }
            return false;
        });
}
```

Código da estrutura da minha `migrate`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('info_adds', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('descricao', 170);
        $table->integer('user_created')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_created', 'info_add_created_user')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_updated')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_updated', 'info_add_updated_user')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['user_created', 'descricao'], 'user_description_infoadd');
    });
}
```

Código do meu `request` método `rules`:

```
 public function rules()
 {
    return [
        'descricao' => 'required|uniquekeyduple:user_description_infoadd|max:300',
    ];
}
```

***Código do meu request método messages:***

```
public function messages(){
    return [
        'descricao.required'=>'É necessário informar uma descrição!',
        'descricao.max'=>'Número de caracteres excedido,informe no máximo 300 caracteres!',
        'descricao.uniquekeyduple' => 'ERRO!',
        ];
}
```

***Método `Controller`:***

```
public function store(InfoAddRequest $request)
{        

    InfoAdd::create($request->all());

    Session::flash('infAddMsg', 'Informação gravada com sucesso!');

    return redirect('/infoadd/list');

}
```

***Registro em providers:***

```
'providers' => 
[
    Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\UniqueKeyDupleServiceProvider::class,
    Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
```

Consegui validar, mas ele me diz que já existe, sendo que não cadastrei nada no banco de dados ainda! talvez seja erro na logica do provider, mas não entendi bem o funcionamento do provider.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso mesmo, por exemplo. Eu tenho o usuario ulisses com código 1, se ele cadastrar (DESCRIÇÃO) DESCARGA (USUARIO) 1, Não poderá mais cadastrar essa informação, mas o usuário 2 poderá, uma única vez também..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [tutorial descrito aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157107/54880) não foi ***observado corretamente***, no seu código está errado como se chama a validação, porque na *`descricao`* tem que ser colocado *`user_created`*, veja como seria a chamada correta:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'descricao' => 'required|uniquekeyduple:user_created|max:300',
    ];
}
```

o outro problema encontrado, é porque, o tutorial anterior verificava dois inteiros, nesse caso um é uma `string` (texto) e um inteiro, então tem que mudar:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Validator::extend('uniquekeyduple',
        function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
        {
            $value1 = (int)request()->get($parameters[0]);
            if (!empty($value) && is_numeric($value1))
            {
                return (!(InfoAdd::where($attribute, $value)
                        ->where($parameters[0], $value1)
                        ->count() > 0));
            }
            return false;
        });
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers)
- [Registering Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#registering-providers)
- [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules)